# Facing issues with File resouce with folder name called "environment" in puppet

Tags: file, resources, puppet, fileserver, puppet-enterprise

I am trying to recursively transfer files from puppet master to my agents with inbuilt fileservers.

I am having folder name called "environment" which is not been transferred to my agents. Instead I am getting the following errors

```
 Error: Could not set 'file' on ensure: Error 404 on SERVER: {"message":"Not Found: file1.txt is not a known environment","issue_kind":"RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND"}
 Error: Could not set 'file' on ensure: Error 404 on SERVER: {"message":"Not Found: file1.txt is not a known environment","issue_kind":"RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND"}
 Wrapped exception:
 Error 404 on SERVER: {"message":"Not Found: file1.txt is not a known environment","issue_kind":"RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND"}
 Error: /Stage[main]/Platform::Configuration::Test1/File[/opt/pe-platform-test/test2/file1.txt]/ensure: change from absent to file failed: Could not set 'file' on ensure: Error 404 on SERVER: {"message":"Not Found: file1.txt is not a known environment","issue_kind":"RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND"}
```

My actual code below

```
class platform::configuration::test1 {

  file { "/opt/pe-platform-test/test2":
    ensure  => "directory",
    source  =>  "puppet://puppetmaster.sample.net/puppet_plat_shared/environment",
    source_permissions=>"use",
    ignore  => [".svn"],
    replace => "true",
    recurse => "remote",
  }

}
```

Comment: Please specify what version of puppet you're using and any relevant `fileserver.conf` settings.

Answer (score 1):

The word "environment" is a [reserved word in Puppet 4.x](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_reserved.html#reserved-words), you can try wrapping the source in single quotes or changing the name of the directory?

Comment: can you explain clearly about wrapping the source in single quote?